# Creating project variables automatically on DataStage 7.5

Tags: automation, environment-variables, jobs, datastage

I have developed a lot of DataStage 7.5 jobs and I must to delivey them to testing and then to production environment. I used, in the jobs, *User Defined* project variables and I'm looking for a procedure to automatically create these variables in different environments.

For DataStage 9.1, there is the ability to export and then import the variables in the section Environment variables of InfoSphere DataStage Administration, as on following image:
[image]
There is a simple solution other than manually entering the variables ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution. For DataStage version 7.5 there is an executable DSAdmin which it can perform some administrative tasks. For *User Defined project variables*, exist option **envadd**

The command dsadmin is located in the $DS_HOME/bin directory and has the syntax as the following example:

```
$DS_HOME/bin/dsadmin -server 192.168.0.1:31359 -user dsadm -password dsadmExample -envadd OracleDBSourceName -type STRING -prompt "Oracle DB Source Name" -value ora_source dts_proj
```

where

192.168.0.1:31359 = DataStage Server Ip and port

dsadm/dsadmExample = user and password of DataStage administrative user

OracleDBSourceName = user variable name

STRING = type of variable; can be STRING or ENCRYPTED

"Oracle DB Source Name" = prompt for variable presented to user

ora_source = variable default value

dts_proj = DataStage project name to add variable

DsAdmin command can be used for other admministrative task as such as create a project, list project properties and user variables, change project properties